# error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'bson'

Tags: mongodb, typescript, npm-install, typescript-typings, bson

I can not find the type definition file for 'bson' "with a TS2688 error: Can not find type definition file for 'bson'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEObh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried npm i @types/bson --save-dev? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bson

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Some packages come with their typings when you install the package itself and others are usually made by people contributing to the DefinitelyTyped project, http://definitelytyped.org/, and are installable via npm i @types/some-package-name--save-dev.